Using COUNTIFS With Criterias Being Arrays That Outputs a Dynamic Array
I am having a problem in EXCEL with the COUNTIFS function where both of my criteria are arrays.

What I need is a function that counts how many times each unique letter in the Table has 1 or 2 associated with it. I would like the output of this to be a dynamic array like the data is in column F, but in Column G.
So, for example, column F and G would look like



Column F
Column G




A
4


B
2


C
2



And so on and so forth.
I have tried doing something along the lines of
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Letter],F1#,Table1[Number],OFFSET(I1,0,0,COUNTA(I1:I48),1)), but this does not yield a correct result.
After digging online, I've seen a bunch of posts saying to combine this kind of formula with the SUM function, but this does not result in a dynamic array. I would get the correct value in cell G1 but have to fill handle it down to the rest of the F Column values, which I don't want in case the length of values in column F change. I've also seen posts saying to do a SUMPRODUCT function, but this would sum all of the occurrences of column F with the numbers 1 and 2 and put it in a single cell. I want this total value to be shown among each character that exists in Column F. Basically, spill the formula in G1 down to the last value in Column F and show counts associated with each letter in Column F.
Please let me know if this is something that can be done or if there is another way I can go about completing this.

Try: =MAP(F1#,LAMBDA(x, SUM(--(FILTER(Table1[Number],Table1[Letter]=x)={1,2}))))

Commented only when confident that it will definitely work. Also can you first show how it is not working for you, then will explain.

I'm sorry for the confusion, but it did end up working. Thanks again so much for the help!
